# Not Redirecting to another web application (Distinct tomcat instances)

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-web-services, servlets

What is need to be done ?

Need to redirect from one web application to another web application `with some data` (User registration information). Both web application uses `tomcat8` server `but deployed on distinct instances`

What I have tried ?

At first web app

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(u);
response.sendRedirect("http://securestorageaudits-env.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/data?user="+json);
```

At second web app, I have servelet data.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    User userObject = new Gson().fromJson(user, User.class);
    /// my code to process userObject
}
```

Problem

1. It is not redirecting to specified url when I deploy this on AWS
   (Distinct tomcat instances)

*It does not work when*

```
 url = response.sendRedirect("http://securestorageaudits-env.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com**/data?user="+json**);
```

2. It is redirecting to specified url locally (same tomcat
   instances)
3. It is  redirecting to specified url even on AWS with Distinct
   tomcat `instances but without parameter`

*It's working when*

```
url= response.sendRedirect("http://securestorageaudits-env.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com");
```

I am newbie to jsp-servlet, please guide on this.

Comment: Items 1 and 3 seem to contradict each other. Is it performing the redirect or not?

Comment: On item #1 when you say it doesn't work, is there any error message in the server log? Is there any error message in the browser console?

Comment: @MarkB No there is no any error msg on browser